# CSS grid - Group labels and input separately in HTML

Tags: html, css, css-grid, css-tables

Due to need of creating 350+ pair of label/input, I would like to have the label and input grouped separately in HTML. The solution I have with CSS grid "container-1" works fine when the label and input comes in pairs.

Update: The second reason I would like to keep label/input separately is because I will later use a for-loop and inject data from imported array.

Question: How can I make "container-2" result in same output as "container-1" with no changes of HTML and  minimal adjustment of CSS ?
I want to stick to CSS grid.

```css
.container_1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.container_2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>container-1</h2>

  <div class='container_1'>

    <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
    <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
    <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
    <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
    <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
    <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
  </div>

<br><br>

<h2>container-2</h2>

  <div class='container_2'>

    <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
    <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
    <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>

    <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
    <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
    <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you need container 2 to have the same appearance as container 1?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes, same output.

Comment: Does applying the same CSS rules to both containers not work?

Comment: @FluffyKitten No it does not work, see code snippet.

Comment: like this? - https://ibb.co/kHcsVsF

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes!

Comment: Based on answers so far it seem to not be possible to let HTML be intact as-is. I think it is bit strange because it should not matter if grouping label and input, due to label finds input based on input name attribute. It should be possible to control from CSS or in worst case adjust the order using PHP.

Comment: This is not entirely true for grid. This is the principle of grid layout. You will see them in the exact order in which you placed them.

Comment: Everything is possible, look at my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Changed [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) of the second container to change the direction. No changes in HTML.

Althought here you have to determine [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) of `label` and `input`.

```css
.container_1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.container_2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.container_2 label {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.container_2 input {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>container-1</h2>

  <div class='container_1'>

    <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
    <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
    <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
    <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
    <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
    <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
  </div>

<br><br>

<h2>container-2</h2>

  <div class='container_2'>

    <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
    <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
    <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>

    <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
    <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
    <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but what's the point in torturing yourself like that if you can place elements in the second container in the same way as in the first one :))

Comment: Like the author of the question said "Due to need of creating 350+ pair of label/input, I would like to have the label and input grouped separately in HTML. The second reason I would like to keep label/input separately is because I will later use a for-loop and inject data from imported array." The question was about to keep label and input separately. I agree, with you, but the author of the question - doesn't)

Comment: - To clarify, the whole purpose of the question was to keep the label and input separate and grouped for later for-loops processing. The 1st container purpose was only a reference of what I could achieve, meanwhile the 2nd container was meant to be the one to be updated according to mentioned requirements/needs.

Comment: I'll take note of your layout. come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container_1 {/* Your HTML for bottom and top just needs to be the same*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.container_2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>container-1</h2>

  <div class='container_1'>

    <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
    <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
    <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
    <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
    <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
    <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
  </div>

<br><br>

<h2>container-2</h2>

  <div class='container_2'>
      <label for="dummy1">title for dummy1:</label>
      <input id="dummy1" name="dummy1" value="dummy1">
      <label for="dummy2">longer title for dummy2:</label>
      <input id="dummy2" name="dummy2" value="dummy2">
      <label for="dummy3">even longer title for dummy3:</label>
      <input id="dummy3" name="dummy3" value="dummy3">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```